# How to show response messages returned from rest service?

Tags: java, ajax, rest

In my application I do not use ajax to post data into server. I get the data with @FormParam annotations. When I insert data or when I get an error, response message is shown in a blank page. What I want to do is I want to show this message on the same page. But I don't know how to do it. When I try to use ajax to send data I always get error. That is why I did not use it.

This is my form:

```
<form action="Rest/hastaService/insertHasta" method="post"
            name="myForm">

                    <input class="form-control" type="input" id="tcKimlik"
                        name="tcKimlik" size="11" maxlength="11" required
                        pattern="[0-9]{11}">

                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="isim" id="isim">

                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="soyisim" id="soyisim">

                    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="dogum" id="dogum">

                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="meslek" id="meslek">

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Kaydet" />
        </form>
```

Server Side :

```
@POST
    @Path("/insertHasta")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response createHastalar(@FormParam("tcKimlik") long tcKimlik, @FormParam("isim") String isim,
            @FormParam("soyisim") String soyIsim, @FormParam("dogum") String dogumTarih,
            @FormParam("meslek") String meslek) throws SQLException {

        Hasta hasta = new Hasta();

        List<Hasta> hastaList = new ArrayList<Hasta>();

        hasta.setTcKimlik(tcKimlik);
        hasta.setIsim(isim);
        hasta.setSoyIsim(soyIsim);
        hasta.setDogumTarih(dogumTarih);
        hasta.setMeslek(meslek);

        /*Check for hasta if they have appointment*/

        if(access.randevuAra(tcKimlik) == true){
          if(access.hastaAra(tcKimlik) == false){
            hastaList.add(hasta);
                if(access.saveHasta(hastaList) == true){
                    return Response.ok("Basariyla Kaydedildi!", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
                }else{
                    return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Hata!").build();
                }
            }else{
                return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Hasta kaydı zaten var!").build();
            }
        }else{
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Hasta Randevusu Bulunmamaktadir. Lutfen Randevu Aliniz!").build();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is error ? if you can paste error message, i can help you

Comment: When the user submits the form you return raw JSON.  What is processing the JSON on the browser end?  Are you doing something else in code we can't see to return a new page after the POST?  There's quite a bit missing her.

Comment: I added this code now : This also works, maybe I can grab the response from here.

Comment: function submitForm(form){
       var url = form.attr("action");
       var formData = $(form).serializeArray();
       $.post(url, formData).done(function (data) {
           alert(data);
       });
   }

Comment: This is supposed to show the response on alert isn't it?

Comment: Ok I did it thsnks for the answers.